Faster way to sync _one_ Music file to IOS?
A bug in Music sync that has survived many OS updates is that it sometimes fails to recognize a track that has changed.  (It also wastes a lot of time copying files that have not changed onto IOS.)
When I change audio and/or ID3 tags on an MP3 file in my Music library, I have to do something to remove the file, sync, put the file back, and sync again.  So I have to wait twice for transferring files that have not changed, and sometimes have to wait for a second backup.
Is there a low-risk other way to do it?  It would be nice to select the file in Music and trigger updating just that track in the IOS library.

(I have suggested to Apple to put that on the context menu for a selected track.  I have also reported—five years ago—the bugs for not copying changes and copying things that haven't changed.)

How exactly do you change the data in the track? Do you modify it in Music, or change it directly on disk?

Often I edit the audio with Amadeus.  Music updates the duration the next time it is played or Get Info is invoked.  And I add or change ID3 tags, which also Music recognizes on play or Get Info.  Also, I add cover art which Music recognizes.  If I add it with Music, it gets hidden away separately, while if I put it in the file, Music displays it but does not remove it from the file.

However, I have found that if I change metadata in Get Info, the failure to sync still occurs.
